# How do I create a CSV file without the CSV class?

Tags: ruby

I'm using a Mac OSX version 10.8

I'm trying to create a CSV file the old fashion way, but there is a bug in my code. It should create a spreadsheet with three rows, i.e., header, and two rows of data beneath it:

```
File.open('table.csv', 'w') do |f|
    f.puts.each {|line| puts line}
    'Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adj Close'
    '10/8/2013','1676.22','1676.79','1655.03','1655.45','3569230000','1655.45'
    '10/7/2013','1687.15','1687.15','1674.7','1676.12','2678490000','1676.12'
end
```

Can someone fix this so that it works and explain what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is going wrong? What error(s) do you get?

Comment: Is this the actual code? What are these strings making there? Or is that the output as demonstration?

Comment: what is `line`? Where is the data coming from that you're trying to print into the file?

Comment: test.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
'Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adj Close'
       ^

Comment: the data is hard-coded and is inside of my ruby file called test.rb

Comment: Please show your actual code, the above has several syntax errors.

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent a wheel? CSV is a much-abused standard, which happens because people try to reinvent what they imagine is a simple format, until they run into cases where their column separator is embedded in a string and don't encode it correctly, and, again, emit invalid CSV data.

Answer (score 1):

```
File.open('table.csv', 'w') do |csv|
csv << ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adj Close"]
csv << ["10/8/2013","1676.22","1676.79","1655.03","1655.45","3569230000","1655.45"] 
csv << ["10/7/2013","1687.15","1687.15","1674.7","1676.12","2678490000","1676.12"]
end
```

This should work. You don't need an array.

Comment: Thank you for this alternate method

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your data in an array and then loop over it like this:

```
data = [                                                                      
  ['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','Adj Close'],                  
  ['10/8/2013','1676.22','1676.79','1655.03','1655.45','3569230000','1655.45']
  ['10/7/2013','1687.15','1687.15','1674.7','1676.12','2678490000','1676.12'],
]                                                                             
File.open('table.csv', 'w') do |f|                                            
  data.each{|line| f.puts line.join(',')}                                     
end
```

Comment: Question: Without the .join(',') the cell will print down a single column. So what is .join(',') actually doing? Can you please explain in layman's terms. Thanks

Comment: The `join(',')` is taking all the elements of the array and creating a string by appending ("joining") them together with a ',' between each element. so `['a','b','c'].join(',')` returns the string `"a,b,c"`. Without the join you're passing an array to `puts` which will print each element of the array on a separate line. The `join` is building a comma delimited string to pass to `puts` that it will print on a single line.

Comment: What happens if one of the strings contains "foo,bar" and you write out the data, then try to read it in?

Comment: true. If your data can contain commas then you'll need to start escaping things. At that point I'd recommend just using the [CSV class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html). No sense re-inventing the wheel.